# Rewrite using Java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, iteration, java-stream

Well, I wanted to understand if it is possible to rewrite below code using streams? If someone can explain why we can rule out streams here at first place.

```
for (int i=0;i<size; i++) {
    int j = i+1;
    while (j<size && Math.abs(arr1[j]-arr1[i])<=k ) {
        if (Math.abs(arr1[j]-arr1[i])==k) {
             cnt++;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong the equivalent nested `for` loop for this would look like `for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                if (Math.abs(arr[j] - arr[i]) > k) {
                    break;
                }
                if (Math.abs(arr[j] - arr[i]) == k) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        } ` and I believe streams is not the way to go for it. But, could you list what exactly are you trying to achieve here? (what's the problem statement)

Comment: i mean to ask to how do i rewrite for and nested while with streams?

Comment: Voting to reopen since this question is not _"too broad"_ at all. It presents _"a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer"_.

Comment: if you used java 11 it's possible to write nest iterate. @AmitNaik

Comment: Thanks @NgSharma, will check Java 11 options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: ...understand if it is possible to rewrite...

Yes, it is possible, yet heavily discouraged. Please, take this to count and remember that [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) is not a 1:1 substitution to the [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) in most cases.

> Q: ...why we can rule out streams here at first place...

The Streams are not suitable for indices repetitive usage or their re-usage at all. The idea of Streams is monad and suitable to traverse through the collection/array **once** and produce a declared output.

There is a way using [`IntStream::range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) as a substitution for the iteration through an array using indices, however, it brings **no-real** benefit to the solution and moreover, is significantly more verbose and of lower clarity. On top of that, I cannot picture a solution that basically doesn't violate the key principles of [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

- Non-interference
- Stateless behaviors
- Side-effects free

The typical use-cases for [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) is filtering, flat/mapping, reducing, collecting to a collection or grouping to a `Map` with or without the aggregation operations usage, etc... They are suitable for parallel processing as well.